# Printing parsed JSON

Tags: json, node.js, loops

So, I've parsed a response like this:

```
var g_rgListingInfo = JSON.parse( response );
```

response looks like this

> {"321242653847396921":{"listingid":"321242653847396921","price":28338,"fee":4249,"publisher_fee_app":730,"publisher_fee_percent":"0.10000000149011612","currencyid":"2003","steam_fee":1416,"publisher_fee":2833,"asset":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"3038615825","amount":"1","market_actions":[{"link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D1030942533801731526","name":"Inspect in Game..."}]}},"321242653843485871":{"listingid":"321242653843485871","price":30175,"fee":4525,"publisher_fee_app":730,"publisher_fee_percent":"0.10000000149011612","currencyid":"2003","steam_fee":1508,"publisher_fee":3017,"asset":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"1730491611","amount":"1","market_actions":[{"link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D1030942533801731526","name":"Inspect in Game..."}]}},"782860982384213986":{"listingid":"782860982384213986","price":31305,"fee":4695,"publisher_fee_app":730,"publisher_fee_percent":"0.10000000149011612","currencyid":"2003","steam_fee":1565,"publisher_fee":3130,"asset":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"2815962367","amount":"1","market_actions":[{"link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D1030942533801731526","name":"Inspect in Game..."}]}},"783987515556891867":{"listingid":"783987515556891867","price":31305,"fee":4695,"publisher_fee_app":730,"publisher_fee_percent":"0.10000000149011612","currencyid":"2003","steam_fee":1565,"publisher_fee":3130,"asset":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"3708699202","amount":"1","market_actions":[{"link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D1030942533801731526","name":"Inspect in Game..."}]}},"783987515558623437":{"listingid":"783987515558623437","price":30957,"fee":4642,"publisher_fee_app":730,"publisher_fee_percent":"0.10000000149011612","currencyid":"2003","steam_fee":1547,"publisher_fee":3095,"asset":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"4462433815","amount":"1","market_actions":[{"link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D1030942533801731526","name":"Inspect in Game..."}]}},"718685320959305952":{"listingid":"718685320959305952","price":34000,"fee":5100,"publisher_fee_app":730,"publisher_fee_percent":"0.10000000149011612","currencyid":"2001","steam_fee":1700,"publisher_fee":3400,"asset":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"4450043953","amount":"1","market_actions":[{"link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D1030942533801731526","name":"Inspect in Game..."}]}},"796369492002647568":{"listingid":"796369492002647568","price":34500,"fee":5175,"publisher_fee_app":730,"publisher_fee_percent":"0.10000000149011612","currencyid":"2001","steam_fee":1725,"publisher_fee":3450,"asset":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"4024113558","amount":"1","market_actions":[{"link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D3082226233578562378","name":"Inspect in Game..."}]}},"718684619833530742":{"listingid":"718684619833530742","price":22958,"fee":3442,"publisher_fee_app":730,"publisher_fee_percent":"0.10000000149011612","currencyid":"2002","steam_fee":1147,"publisher_fee":2295,"asset":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"4331886445","amount":"1","market_actions":[{"link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D1030942533801731526","name":"Inspect in Game..."}]}},"788487401257494747":{"listingid":"788487401257494747","price":34783,"fee":5217,"publisher_fee_app":730,"publisher_fee_percent":"0.10000000149011612","currencyid":"2001","steam_fee":1739,"publisher_fee":3478,"asset":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"2315637005","amount":"1","market_actions":[{"link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D1030942533801731526","name":"Inspect in Game..."}]}},"321242020664839911":{"listingid":"321242020664839911","price":34783,"fee":5217,"publisher_fee_app":730,"publisher_fee_percent":"0.10000000149011612","currencyid":"2001","steam_fee":1739,"publisher_fee":3478,"asset":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"4283078084","amount":"1","market_actions":[{"link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D6944696178921031564","name":"Inspect in Game..."}]}}}

I put it in here: http://json.parser.online.fr/ this is the 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzUh2.png)

The problem I'm having is that I fail to loop through the items. g_rgListingInfo.length is NaN. I tried to use forEach but that failed too.

I want to loop through all these "321242653847396921", "321242653843485871"... wich are always changing and obtain their listingid, price, fee etc.

I am pretty new to node.js so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an object, not an array. So, to iterate the results, you have to either convert your object into an array or just iterate it as object.

#### Converting into array

Depending on what you need, this could be more convenient:

```
var myData = Object.keys(g_rgListingInfo).map(Number).sort().map(function (c) {
     return g_rgListingInfo[c];
});

// Then you can just use the `myData` array
myData.forEach(function (current, index) {
    /* do something */
});

// ...or using for loop
for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; ++i) {
    var current = myData[i];
    /* do something */
}
```

#### Iterating the object

You have to get the keys of the object iterate them (optionally you maybe want to sort them first).

```
// ["3124...", ...]
var numbers = Object.keys(g_rgListingInfo);

// Optional sort
numbers = numbers.map(Number).sort();

// Iterate the object keys
numbers.forEach(function (currentKey) {
    var currentObject = g_rgListingInfo[currentKey];
});
```